# How to unmarhal JSON into dynamodb.AttributeValue?

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

On input I have for example:

```
[
        {
            "M": {
                "Capacity": {
                    "S": "7"
                },
                "Energy": {
                    "S": "A+"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "M": {
                "Capacity": {
                    "S": "7"
                },
                "Energy": {
                    "S": "A++"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "M": {
                "Capacity": {
                    "S": "7"
                },
                "Energy": {
                    "S": "A+++"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

And instead of `Capacity`, `Energy` I can get other keys. I did not find any way how to prepare from such input `dynamodb.AttributeValue` applicable for `UpdateItem`.

I tried to unmarshal into `[]map[string]interface{}` and then cast to `dynamodb.AttributeValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unmarshal into `[]map[string]map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{}` then `Capacity` and  `Energy` key are unmarshal as `dynamodb.AttributeValue`.

So, you can use outer map's value of type `map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue` as `ExpressionAttributeValues` in `UpdateItemInput` to `UpdateItem`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
)
func main() {
    data := []byte(`[
        {
            "M": {
                "Capacity": {
                    "S": "7"
                },
                "Energy": {
                    "S": "A+"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "M": {
                "Capacity": {
                    "S": "7"
                },
                "Energy": {
                    "S": "A++"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "M": {
                "Capacity": {
                    "S": "7"
                },
                "Energy": {
                    "S": "A+++"
                }
            }
        }
    ]`)

    d := []map[string]map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{}
    json.Unmarshal(data, &d)
    for _, mp := range d {
        expressionAttributeValues := mp["M"]
        // you can use expressionAttributeValues as ExpressionAttributeValues in UpdateItemInput to UpdateItem
        capacity := expressionAttributeValues["Capacity"]
        energy := expressionAttributeValues["Energy"]
        fmt.Printf("%+v", capacity)
        fmt.Printf("%+v", energy)
    }
}
```